# How can I allow users to specify one main taxonomy term from a set of terms?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

In my node edit form, I have a field that allows users to select multiple terms from a fixed list to designate "categories" that the node is part of. I would like the user to be able to specify that a single one of these terms is the "main" category for the node, so that the node has one single "main" category, together with an arbitrary number of implicitly "secondary" categories from the same vocabulary. I am using Drupal 7.x.

Comment: Why not just add another term reference field with single value, and call it "Main category"?

Comment: I thought there might be a more elegant solution, not having to duplicate the field.

Comment: Well you can write your own field widget which allows you to specify a "main item" using radios. But then again that widget will only be used for 1 field for your only project, it's elegant but it's also a sledgehammer to crack a nut. My 2 cents. Hope someone else can find a simpler and more elegant solution.